# python parse every loop items in json response

Tags: python, json, object, response

i have json response like this :

```
r =  {
        "ID": "0001",
        "ST": "87549937737",
        "DT": "22062022",
        "DATA": {
            "0": {
                "PC": "100",
                "NM": "ALEX",
                "AMOUNT": "210,912",
                "ACT": "123123456"
            },
            "1": {
                "PC": "100",
                "NM": "MARCO",
                "AMOUNT": "500,200",
                "ACT": "123555456"
            },
            "2": {
                "PC": "100",
                "NM": "TIFFANY",
                "AMOUNT": "712,111",
                "ACT": "123666981"
            }
        },
        "RCMSG": {
            "0": {
                "SEVERITY": "00"
            }
        },
        "RC": "0000"
    }
```

and i want to parse every loop items in DATA, and my scripts are like this :

```
for items in r['DATA']:
    jdata = {'PRODUCTCODE': items['PC'], 'NAME': items['NM'], 'AMOUNTBALANCE': items['AMOUNT'], 'ACCOUNT': items['ACT']}
    return jsonify({'status':'success', 'code':'00', 'data': jdata})
```

but the response is only parsed '0' in 'DATA, how do i loop every items inside 'DATA' ?

```
{
    "PRODUCTCODE": "100",
    "NAME": "ALEX",
    "AMOUNTBALANCE": "210,912",
    "ACCOUNT": "123123456"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
results = []
for k, v in r['DATA'].items():
    item = {
        "PRODUCTCODE": v["PC"],
        "NAME": v["NM"],
        "AMOUNTBALANCE": v["AMOUNT"],
        "ACCOUNT": v["ACT"],
    }
    results.append(item)
```

Comment: it works too, but now i need to return all these values using flask.

Comment: @user15167308 use the `results` variable because it contains the items you need

Comment: {
 "status": "success",
 "code": "00",
 "data": [
  {
   "PRODUCTCODE": "100",
   "NAME": "ALEX",
   "AMOUNTBALANCE": "210,912",
   "ACCOUNT": "123123456"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: but it ended up like this.
results = []
for k, v in r['DATA'].items():
    item = {
        "PRODUCTCODE": v["PC"],
        "NAME": v["NM"],
        "AMOUNTBALANCE": v["AMOUNT"],
        "ACCOUNT": v["ACT"],
    }
    results.append(item)
return jsonify({'status':'success', 'code':'00', 'data': results})

Answer (score 1):

In your code, there is a `return` statement inside the for loop, so it will never traverse all elements in `JSON` data because it will end its execution at the first item. So, you need to traverse all elements accessing them from the original `JSON` response:

```
r =  {
        "ID": "0001",
        "ST": "87549937737",
        "DT": "22062022",
        "DATA": {
            "0": {
                "PC": "100",
                "NM": "ALEX",
                "AMOUNT": "210,912",
                "ACT": "123123456"
            },
            "1": {
                "PC": "100",
                "NM": "MARCO",
                "AMOUNT": "500,200",
                "ACT": "123555456"
            },
            "2": {
                "PC": "100",
                "NM": "TIFFANY",
                "AMOUNT": "712,111",
                "ACT": "123666981"
            }
        },
        "RCMSG": {
            "0": {
                "SEVERITY": "00"
            }
        },
        "RC": "0000"
    }
d = []
for i in r['DATA']:
    d.append(r['DATA'][i])
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'PC': '100', 'NM': 'ALEX', 'AMOUNT': '210,912', 'ACT': '123123456'}, {'PC': '100', 'NM': 'MARCO', 'AMOUNT': '500,200', 'ACT': '123555456'}, {'PC': '100', 'NM': 'TIFFANY', 'AMOUNT': '712,111', 'ACT': '123666981'}]
```

Comment: so how do i return all these values using flask if return statement cannot traverse all elements in JSON DATA ?

Comment: @user15167308 You can return, in this case the `d` variable, containing all the traversed elements